# BIRT Runtime 4.7.0 - How to set --locale

Tags: locale, birt

I'm trying to run a few Reports that have the current month name in them. I'm generating them using genReport.sh from the Birt Runtime. In genReport.sh it states that I can pass "--locale" without specifing how to. So I tried a few different scenarios "de_DE", "de", "de-DE", "DE" without success. My report will get generated with the english month name instead of the german one.

The date name is a column binding that has the following javascript in them:

```
currentDate = new Date()
prev = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() - 1)

options = { month: 'long', year: 'numeric'}

prev.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options).slice(3)
```

How can I pass the german locale to the genReport.sh ?

Comment: Why do you slice it?

Comment: Because while a more modern Javascript will output only "Febuary 2018" with the code above, in Birt it will return "01 Febuary 2018". So I slice it because I only need the month and the year.